# Drools. Container in Kie server not updated when rule updated in Workbench

Tags: docker, drools, workbench

I'm developing an app using Java and Drools.

Firstly I created a new rule service, created a data object, and finally a guided rule, which I built and deployed into the kie server.

After that, I created a java class for testing it, and it is working as expected. The problem is that if I update the rule and deploy it again then the server keeps giving the same answer, as if nothing were changed.

I also tried the service from postman, via REST interface, but the problem is the same.

I have restarted the kie server, workbench (one docker for each one, linked), and it doesn't work even if I delete the project from the server and deploy it again.

I think it must be related to the way that the server and workbench are notified, but I have tried everything and the problem persists.

This is the code I am actually using to execute the rule service:

```
public void executeCommands() {

    ErrorWK err=new ErrorWK();
    err.setErrorApp("NotifyEmployee");
    err.setErrorCode("111");
    err.setErrorDesc("Error in the service");


    KieServicesConfiguration config = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(
            URL,USER,PASSWORD);
    Set<Class<?>> allClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    allClasses.add(ErrorWK.class);
    config.addExtraClasses(allClasses);

    KieServicesClient rulesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(config);     



    System.out.println("== Sending commands to the server ==");
    KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();


    Command<?> insert = commandsFactory.newInsert(err, "InObject", false, "");

    Command<?> fireAllRules = commandsFactory.newFireAllRules("Fired");

    Command<?> getObjects = commandsFactory.newGetObjects("OutObject");
    Command<?> dispose=commandsFactory.newDispose();

    Command<?> batchCommand = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(Arrays.asList(insert, fireAllRules,getObjects, dispose));

    ServiceResponse<String> executeResponse = rulesClient.executeCommands("WorkshopBRMS_1.0.1", batchCommand);

    Marshaller marshaller = MarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(config.getExtraClasses(), MarshallingFormat.JAXB, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    ExecutionResultImpl results = marshaller.unmarshall(executeResponse.getResult(), ExecutionResultImpl.class);

    ArrayList<Object> objects = (ArrayList<Object>) results.getResults().get("OutObject");  
    System.out.println("Rules fired: " + results.getValue("Fired"));
    //System.out.println(objects); 

    for(java.util.Iterator<Object> it=objects.iterator();it.hasNext();) {

        Object obj=(Object) it.next();

        if(obj instanceof ErrorWK){

            ErrorWK test= (ErrorWK)obj;
            System.out.println("Error: " + test.getErrorApp() + "/" + test.getErrorCode() + "/" + test.getErrorDesc());
            System.out.println("_________________________________________________________________________________");
        }else {

            System.out.println("Object does not belong to any of the defined classes:" + obj.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can consider below approaches:

1. keep the project version fix(ex. 1.0.0) and enable kie-Scanner on kie-server. Kie-Scanner API's will keep scanning maven repository to check if latest version of project is available or not.
2. While deploying project(creating kie-container) in kie-server use LATEST in version of project, and enable kie-scanner. Now kie-scanner will always use latest version of project available in maven repository. But LATEST will not not work if your project has SNAPSHOT release,its known limitation of maven.
3. After rule modification increase the project version and create now kie-container to use latest version if project. I personally dont recommend this approach.

Go through https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch19.html#d0e19362 for more details on kie-scanner.